# Ubuntu guest on Vista host using Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization

I just got it setup and I don't have a lot of experience in virtualization, so please bear with me!
I have set up the RAM for the guest (ubuntu10.10) as 512 MB and hard disk space 8 gb. It runs very very slowly. Any suggestions on how I should go about bettering it?
I have a Dell Inspiron, Intel® Pentium® Dual Core T4200 (2.0GHz/800Mhz FSB/1MB cache) machine with Vista.

thanks a lot
-beanyblue

Comment: We need to see the output of dmesg and /var/log/messages. Also, what's "slow" to one person might be different to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Stop the VM , edit the xml file inside the VM folder and try to set "HardwareVirtEx enabled="true"", it should work like a charm.

Comment: IIRC the T4200 doesn't support hardware virtualisation features, will this still work in that case?

Comment: @Robert No, it won't and probably it's the reason why you have performance issues, but maybe others have some ideas.